# jQuery .not или :not

Tags: jquery

Начал изучать данный язык - и возник вопрос:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="http://jquery.com">jQuery</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
      <li>Ale!</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>jQuery
    <ul>
      <li>tazt</li>
      <li>tezt</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Мне надо выбрать `<li>Ale!</li>` - через not. Составил `$('ul.myList>li:first-child li a')`. Вот в конце надо поменять на "НЕ(А)", что б оно возвращало все элементы помимо А.

(В данном случае вернет только А.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

стоит обратится к документации 
**[:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** :

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

с одной стороны они утверждают, что `.not()` более читабельно при сложных селекторах, что на мой взгляд спорно, но с другой стороны `:not()` намного быстрее в работе: [пруф.](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not)

в вашем случае:

```
$('ul.myList>li:first-child li:not(:has(a))')
```

кстати, у вас `<ul class="list">` а в слекторе `myList`